# How can I create .nii (nifti) file from 3D Numpy array

Tags: pytorch, numpy, image-segmentation

I have a prediction numpy array. How can I make a .nii or .nii.gz mask file from the array?

Comment: The [`nibabel` python package](https://nipy.org/nibabel/) might be able to help you with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can this using [nibabel](https://nipy.org/nibabel/):

```
import nibabel as nb

ni_img = nib.Nifti1Image(numpy_array, affine=np.eye(4))
nib.save(ni_img, "dicom_volume_image.nii")
```